# Ruby: undefined local variable or method work around

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I usually will have some code that looks like the following:

```
return if foo.nil?
bar = foo[:bar] || 0
```

The problem with they above is that if foo[:bar] does not exist, I get an HTTP 500 error because a NameError exception gets thrown that looks something like:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `foo'..)
```

What's a more elegant work around?

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that will make this simpler for you, called [`andand`](http://andand.rubyforge.org/). It'll let you do something like:

```
bar = foo.andand[:bar] || 0
```

It's supposed to be a shorthand for `foo && foo[:bar]`, hence the name.

It also works with methods, by the way. Assuming `foo` can have a method `quux`, you could use

```
foo.andand.quux
```